# SVG zoom in on mouse - mathematical model

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Before you think "why is this guy asking for help on this problem, surely this has been implemented 1000x" - while you are mostly correct, I have attempted to solve this problem with several open source libs yet here I am.

I am attempting to implement an SVG based "zoom in on mouse wheel, focusing on the mouse" from scratch.

I know there are many libraries that accomplish this, d3 and svg-pan-zoom to name a couple. Unfortunately, my implementations using those libs are falling short of my expectations. I was hoping that I could get some help from the community with the underlying mathematical model for this type of UI feature.

Basically, the desired behavior is like Google Maps, a user has their mouse hovering over a location, they scroll the mouse wheel (inward), and the scale of the map image increases, while the location being hovered over becomes the horizontal and vertical center of the viewport.

Naturally, I have access to the width / height of the viewport and the x / y of the mouse.

In this example, I will only focus on the x axis, the viewport is 900 units wide, the square is 100 units wide, it's x offset is 400 units, and the scale is 1:1

```
<g transform="translate(0 0) scale(1)">
```

[image]

Assuming the mouse x position was at or near 450 units, if a user wheels in until scale reached 2:1, I would expect the x offset to reach -450 units, centering the point of focus like so.

```
<g transform="translate(-450 0) scale(2)">
```

[image]

The x and y offsets need to be recalculated on each increment of wheel scroll as a function of the current scale / mouse offsets.

All of my attempts have fallen utterly short of the desired behavior, any advice is appreciated.

While I appreciate any help, please refrain from answering with suggestions to 3rd party libraries, jQuery plugins and things of that nature. My aim here is to understand the mathematical model behind this problem in a general sense, my use of SVG is primarily illustrative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I usually do is I maintain three variable offset x offset y and scale. They will be applied as a transform to a container group, like your element `<g transform="translate(0 0) scale(1)">`.

If the mouse would be over the origin the new translation would be trivial to calculate. You just multiply the offset x and y by the difference in scale :

```
offsetX = offsetX * newScale/scale
offsetY = offsetY * newScale/scale
```

What you could do is translate the offset so that the mouse is at the origin. Then you scale and then you translate every thing back. Have a look at this typescript class that has a scaleRelativeTo method to do just what you want:

```
export class Point implements Interfaces.IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    public constructor(x: number, y: number) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    add(p: Interfaces.IPoint): Point {
      return new Point(this.x + p.x, this.y + p.y);
    }

    snapTo(gridX: number, gridY: number): Point {
      var x = Math.round(this.x / gridX) * gridX;
      var y = Math.round(this.y / gridY) * gridY;
      return new Point(x, y);
    }

    scale(factor: number): Point {
      return new Point(this.x * factor, this.y * factor);
    }

    scaleRelativeTo(point: Interfaces.IPoint, factor: number): Point {

      return this.subtract(point).scale(factor).add(point);
    }

    subtract(p: Interfaces.IPoint): Point {
      return new Point(this.x - p.x, this.y - p.y);
    }

  }
```

So if you have given transform given by `translate(offsetX,offsetY) scale(scale)` and a scroll event took place at `(mouseX, mouseY)` leading to a new scale `newScale` you would calculate the new transform by :

```
offsetX = (offsetX - mouseX) * newScale/scale + mouseX
offsetY = (offsetY - mouseY) * newScale/scale + mouseY
```